# How to disable popup "Close this terminal?" when closing terminal?

Tags: command-line

Each time when I want to close terminal there is a popup with question "Close this terminal?" because some process is running in terminal. I don't care about this process. How to prevent terminal from showing this popup?

Comment: running the command in terminal with `nohup COMMAND & disown` can sometime fix it - this is useful if it is a GUI program like gedit or nautilus.

Answer (score 16):

In 16.04 you'll find that choice in dconf-editor. You can install it, if necessary, with

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then go to

```
org -> gnome -> terminal -> legacy
```

and uncheck `confirm-close`.

Comment: for begginers like me: after install it, run: `dconf-editor` in the terminal and you will see a gui and follow the next instructions.

Comment: You can also launch `dconf-editor` in the GUI. It has an icon and all. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to install `gconf-editor` first. Just open the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

After that, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or open the Dash and type `gconf-editor` and the configuration editor window will appear. Then you go to <kbd>Apps</kbd>→<kbd>Gnome-terminal</kbd>→<kbd>global</kbd> and uncheck the option `confirm_window_close`.

[<sub>Source</sub>](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/07/disable-confirmation-window-when.html)

Comment: It seems like there is nothing under Apps called Gnome-Terminal. However, there is desktop `/`→ `desktop` → `applications` → `terminal` under which such option does not seem to exist, only `exec` and `exec_arg`.

Comment: This works for MATE terminal too, but you have to use `dconf-editor`, the key is under `org.mate.terminal.global`

Comment: This answer is out-of-date now. The correct answer for modern Ubuntu installations is [Hinz's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/999781/560991)

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to cancel any background process that may be running and then you can close the terminal without the popup showing up.

---

### Note:

You can affect your system by closing the terminal with background processes running. A good example is if there is an update or upgrade running, the apt command can get locked up and you may start getting these errors:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?
```

Luckily, they have been solved in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process).

That is just an example of what may happen if you close the terminal when a background process is running. Other things may happen depending on the process itself.

Comment: +0.  You meant well, but I don't think Ctrl+C stops background processes at all.  Please test your answers before you post them.

Comment: This is a warning, not an answer.